# How to force execution in new thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have such code in my app:

```
var t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(new Action(SomeClass.SomeMethod)));
t.Start();
...
t.Join();
```

but as I understand, compiler does some optimization and run SomeMethod in the same thread
as main code. I check this by setting different Names of the thread in t and Thread.CurrentThread. How I can create and run thread to be sure it's new thread.

Comment: It shouldn't 'optimize away' threads in any way...are you sure it does?

Comment: compiler doesn't change the logic of your application to optimize, it's not that much smart. Show us how you came to that conclusion.

Comment: BTW, *why* you care about what *particular* thread your code is executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, if you tell a program to run a task in a new thread, that's exactly what will happen. Those two threads may end up running on the same core (because your calling thread may not do much except wait for the other thread to complete), but you will have two different memory spaces and execution pointers in your process.

An easy way to prove it is to open up task manager, set a breakpoint in SomeMethod, check the thread count of VS (devenv.exe) in the Processes tab, then hit the Debug button to launch your program. When it hits the breakpoint, examine the thread count again; you'll have two new threads, one for the main program execution flow and one for your worker thread. There may be one more for the attached debugger.

Comment: Yep you are exactly right. SomeMethod executed in a different thread.

Comment: The reason of misunderstandings was the point in which I done my observations. Actually it is not all code :) Some method calls Mock object setup earlier.  The Mock raise event as a result of calling and this is the point where threads switched back to main thread. 
Sorry guys. The World is stay still. ;)))

Answer (score 5):

The compiler will *not* optimize your code in that manner. The code will be run in a new .NET thread. There must have been an error in the way you made your observations.

Note that .NET threads aren't necessarily equivalent to OS threads:

> An operating-system ThreadId has no fixed relationship to a managed thread, because an unmanaged host can control the relationship between managed and unmanaged threads. Specifically, a sophisticated host can use the CLR Hosting API to schedule many managed threads against the same operating system thread, or to move a managed thread between different operating system threads.

You could in theory see two managed threads with the same Windows thread ID, but the `Thread.Name` property will still be different (assuming you initally set the names to two different values).

If you could post the code you used where you observed something being run in the wrong thread it might be possible to discover what error you have made.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have made an error in your code. Try this:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "main";

var t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(new Action(SomeClass.SomeMethod))); 
t.Name = "worker";

t.Start(); 
// ... 
t.Join();
```

Be aware that [Thread.Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.name.aspx) is a write-once property. It is therefore a bad idea to name thread pool threads!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the Task library? (if you use .NET 4.0)

```
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
             {
                 // your code here, this will be executed in a Task thread
             });
```

Comment: As I understand from manuals Parallel Extensions Library creating new Task not guarantees that code will run in new thread.

Comment: It's run in a different thread, but might not be run on a different core/processor.